# Filtering using Two RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have two RDD. First one contains

```
(pID, Name, Price, Column1)
```

Second one contains

```
(pID, Seller, Column3)
```

I want to get the column 3 where the pID are the same. I still want to maintain the first RDD format. I couldn't figure out a logic to output this. I'm also troubling with the functional programming logic as well. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
    val as = List((101, ("iteam A", 1.24)),
      (102, ("iteam B", 2.45)),
      (103, ("iteam C", 3.54)))
    val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(as) // Pair Rdd with key = pId, value = (name, price)

    val ls = List((101, "Seller A"),
      (101, "Seller B"),
      (102, "Seller C"),
      (102, "Seller D"),
      (103, "Seller E"))
    val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(ls) // Pair Rdd with key = pId, value = (seller)

    //call inner join:
     val innerJoinedRdd = rdd1.join(rdd2)
     innerJoinedRdd.collect().foreach(println)

    (101,((iteam A,1.24),Seller A))
    (101,((iteam A,1.24),Seller B))
    (102,((iteam B,2.45),Seller C))
    (102,((iteam B,2.45),Seller D))
    (103,((iteam C,3.54),Seller E))
```

Comment: Oh I thought of merging the datasets but didn’t considered joining. (Thought I had to do it manually as I was loading from a csv). Thanks!

Comment: Would this be performance-exhaustive? I'm working on a big dataset that contains  nearly a million entries. Is there a ore efficient way where I can pick only the selected pID items.

Comment: I don't think so. If it takes extra time. Try to convert into dataframe and then applied the join.

Comment: seems it hasn't solved my problem yet. Sorry, but I simplified my dataset columns.
the real dataset contains
A - (pID, column1, column2, column3)
B - (pID, columnA, columnB)

I want the columnB (only matching pIDs) to be added to the A dataset while maintaining the A dataset schema.

Comment: can you update your question? input and desire output

Comment: still the same. where is desired output